# mongodb structure for logging?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, performance, logging

I have a client-server application and I was planning to store the trace and logging on mongodb. My initial idea is to create a document per user session with the common client data (session, ipaddress, userid, dateCreated, etc) and an array for each logging entry for that user in that session. But I read that is not a good practice to have big arrays on mongodb http://www.askasya.com/post/largeembeddedarrays/ on my case, the client session log array could go for thousands of entries.

On the other hand, duplicating the common parameters for each log entry seems a waste of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I created a document to store all the client session data with an ID and a new document per log entry with a property pointing that document by the ID. Even if usually, relationship data should not be used on mongodb, for logging I think is not an issue to do a second query to get the user session data instead duplicating the data on each log or adding all the log entries as a big array.